# QT error in connecting passing a QString element

Tags: qt, signals, qstring

I was following some code posted in other questions on how to connect the status bar between parent and distant child by means of signals and slots.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
  QMainWindow(parent)
{
...
connect(myCanvas,SIGNAL(mouseMoved(QString)),
        this,slot(setStatusBar(QString)));
...
}
```

Somewhere in the class MainWindow the following is declared as public slot:

```
void MainWindow::setStatusBarText(const QString& text) {
statusBar()->showMessage(text);
}
```

in the class to which myCanvas belongs declares the signal:

```
signals:
void mouseMoved(const QString&);
```

And emits the signal:

```
void GraphicsView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *mouseEvent)
{
 ...
     emit mouseMoved(QString("("+QString::number(mouseMoveCatch.x())+";"
        +QString::number(mouseMoveCatch.y())+")"));
 ...
 }
```

I am sure QString is properly included. But when i compile I get an error on the connect line saying "QString does not refer to a value".
I have no clue what this means. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You need to capitalize `SLOT` in your connect line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a case error on the line

```
connect(myCanvas,SIGNAL(mouseMoved(QString)),
    this,slot(setStatusBar(QString)));
```

You should be using `SLOT`, not `slot`.

Comment: Grrrr I feel really stupid for posting this. Thanks a lot. (my code still does not work though)

Comment: If you're using Qt 5, you can avoid this kind of error by using the new connect syntax: `connect(myCanvas, &GraphicsView::mouseMoved, this, &MainWindow::setStatusBarText);`

Comment: I tried but (using 5.2) it gave a huge list of errors

Comment: UPDATE: actually i tried again and see the new syntax works like a charm. I guess I made  a typo there as well. Thanks a lot!